# Why is inhibition of inhibition (reciprocal inhibition) such a common motif in cell signalling?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-signaling

In transcriptional regulation, you often find that positive signals proceed by inhibiting or destroying a protein that is in turn inhibiting or destroying the effector protein. This can be seen in the retinoblastoma - E2F signalling pathway, and many others. I was wondering if there was any direct biological utility, and if so what this utility was.

Comment: You might be interested in reading Uri Alon's take on network motifs: https://doi.org/10.1038/nrg2102

Comment: This reminds me, somehow, of the [Dining Philosophers Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem), which is about avoiding deadlock in distributed systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a my philosophical question...

Direct regulation of proteins would have to have biological utility - such a gene has to be driven by positive selection to adapt that ability.  The question is more about learning what might be driving its role.

I would hazard that protein deactivation and degradation would be important to make sure that these inhibitors could be down-regulated fast enough - if they were left to degrade via a general pathway, the specific signal would not be available for too long a time.